# Why does TensorFlow Conv2D have two weights matrices?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a [`tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) constructed like so:

```py
>>> conv2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2)
```

For reference that layer is part of a network where the prior layer is `prior_layer = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2)`.

When I call `conv2d_layer.get_weights()`, it returns a list with two entries:

```py
>>> [w.shape for w in conv2d_layer.get_weights()]
[(3, 3, 64, 128), (128,)]
```

Why are there two `np.ndarray`s in `conv2d_layer.get_weights()`?  What are their respective meanings?

Comment: The first one is for convolution kernel weights, and the second one is for bias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first shape is for the weights of your conv2D, and the second one is the bias for the same layer, which is represented by a vector.

Looking at the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#getweights-method), you can see

> For example, a Dense layer returns a list of two values: the kernel matrix and the bias vector. These can be used to set the weights of another Dense layer:

Answer (score 1):

You have `128` convolution filters, each filter has a bias and a kernel. The kernel has a size `3x3`. Furthermore, the kernel depth is equal to the input depth (it means `64` in this example). So we have `(3, 3, 64)` for a kernel, and we have `128` filters, so all filter's shapes are equal to `(3, 3, 64, 128)`. Also, we have a bias for every filter so the shape of the second weight is equal to `(128,)`